# Is there a way to pass a custom flag to swift on command line and test for it in source?

Tags: swift

In C it's easy to pass a custom flag on the command line and test for it in a source file, like this:

```
gcc ... -DMY_CUSTOM_FLAG source.c
```

```
// source.c
#ifdef MY_CUSTOM_FLAG
// ...
#else
// ...
#endif
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent in swift?

If not, is there a way to make my source code do something different depending on whether it's being edited in Visual Studio Code (or being parsed by sourcekit-lsp etc) or built as an xcode project for iOS?

Ultimately, what I'm trying to achieve is the ability to do the bulk of my code editing in VS Code despite this being an iPhone app. VS Code only supports Swift Package Manager, but iOS apps can't be 100% SPM. VS Code can easily be tricked into thinking the project is a package for editing purposes by providing a `Package.swift` file, while still using traditional xcode project files in xcode for building and previews. The snag I've hit is that my app uses Firebase, so I need a tiny bit of ObjC code (a function called `tryObjC`) to catch `NSException`s and repackage them as a return value, otherwise it crashes whenever I try to run a preview. SPM doesn't support mixed ObjectiveC and Swift, so I'm looking for a simple way around this, bearing in mind that for editing purposes `tryObjC` doesn't need to be the real deal so could be replaced by a dummy version written in Swift.

Comment: I answered regarding defining compiler directive symbols on the command line, but I wanted to mention that you *can* mix Swift and Obj-C in the same SPM package.  You can't mix them in the same *target*, but you can create two separate targets, one for Swift code, and one for Obj-C code, and have the Swift code depend on the Obj-C code.  I do that in my package, [SwizzleHelper](https://github.com/chipjarred/SwizzleHelper), if you want to look at it to see how that's done.

Comment: I thought of an alternative solution to my specific problem shortly after I posted. It's obvious really, but doesn't really answer the headline question. I used the exclude directive in Package.swift to exclude the Obj-C files, then added a swift file with a dummy implementation of tryObjC, but I only added it to the filesystem, not to the Xcode project. Now VS Code can only see the Swift dummy and XCode can only see the ObjC original.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, even if it side-stepped the original way you were trying to do it.  Sometimes that's the best option anyway.  It's still useful to know how to define compiler directive symbols though, and probably still useful to note that it's possible to mix Obj-C and Swift in the same package, so you'll remember to look up how to do it, if you ever do need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do basically same thing

```bash
swift -D MY_CUSTOM_FLAG ...
```

There is a space after the `-D`.  This sets `MY_CUSTOM_FLAG` to `true`, which otherwise it would be assumed to be `false`:

```swift
#if MY_CUSTOM_FLAG
// code for when MY_CUSTOM_FLAG is defined
#else
// code for when MY_CUSTOM_FLAG is not defined
#endif
```

AFAIK, you can't set it to some arbitrary value like you could do in C/C++/Obj-C.  You just define that the compile-time symbol exists, which makes it evaluate to `true`.

Just remember that Swift doesn't have a preprocessor.  It supports compiler directives, which may seem like a minor distinction, but it means there are lots of things the C preprocessor will do that you can't do with Swift compiler directives, and in Swift even the portions of `#if` statements that *aren't* compiled still have to be syntactically correct.  They don't undergo type-checking or any semantic analysis, but they are checked for syntax.  It also keeps you from doing some of the things you might do in C that it would seem like you could in Swift.

```swift
let defaultSettings: [String: String] =
[
    "theme": "dark",
    #if MY_CUSTOM_FLAG
    "highlightMouse": "on", // <-- Error
    #endif
]
```

In that example you'd have to define two dictionaries.  I'd do something like this to avoid duplication

```swift
fileprivate let commonDefaults: [String: String] =
[
    "theme": "dark",
    // maybe other common settings
]

#if MY_CUSTOM_FLAG 
fileprivate let customFlagDefaults: [String: String] =
[
    "highlightMouse": "on",
    // Maybe other settings
]
#else
fileprivate let customFlagDefaults: [String: String] = [:]
#endif

let defaultSettings = commonDefaults + customFlagDefaults
```